# Writing generated data to database in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

New to jQuery and AJAX here and I’ve been wrestling with a problem. I have a WordPress site that generates random hockey teams. What I’d like to do is give users the option to post one of these random team to the blog. This is where I’m having trouble. It seems to me that the issue is somewhere in my code being able to “read” the form values (if I hard code values in for the variables, it works fine).

I've tried searching Stack Overflow, reading the Codex, blogs, etc, but I'm not understanding where exactly I'm going wrong.

From my functions.php file (truncated for readability):

```
function get_team_desktop() {
//Get random players from database (just showing LW players for readability) 
    $ini = parse_ini_file('config.ini');

    $mysqli = new mysqli($ini['db_host'], $ini['db_user'], $ini['db_password'], $ini['db_name']);
    if($mysqli->connect_error) {
        exit('<h2>Oops! Something went wrong ...</h2>');
        }

    $lwQuery = "SELECT lw.name, lw.number, lw.currentTeam, lw.position, lw.teamAbbr FROM lwing AS lw ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4";

    $lw_result_array = array();

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $lwQuery);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $lw_result_array[] = $row;
        }
    } else {
        echo "<h2>Oops! Something went wrong ...</h2>";
        exit;
    }

    //Output results:
    echo "<div class='player forward col-4'>" . $lw_result_array[0][name] . "<p>#" . $lw_result_array[0][number] . " " . $lw_result_array[0][currentTeam] . " " . "</div>";
    .
    .
    .
    //Add a hidden form that contains all the player data
    echo "<form action='' id='postTeam' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='lw1name' value='" . $lw_result_array[0][name] . "' >
    <input type='hidden' name='lw1number' value='" . $lw_result_array[0][number] . "' >
    <input type='hidden' name='lw1team' value='" . $lw_result_array[0][currentTeam] . "' >";
    .
    .
    .
    echo "<button id='submitTeamButton' type='submit' value='submit'>Post Team to Blog</button>";
    echo "</form>";

    wp_die(); 
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_team_desktop', 'get_team_desktop');
add_action('wp_ajax_get_team_desktop', 'get_team_desktop');

//Function to process form data
function rma_team_post() {

    $ini = parse_ini_file('config.ini');

    $mysqli = new mysqli($ini['db_host'], $ini['db_user'], $ini['db_password'], $ini['db_name']);
    if($mysqli->connect_error) {
        exit('<h2>Oops! Something went wrong ...</h2>');
        }

    $lw1name = $_POST['lw1name'];
    $lw1number = $_POST['lw1number'];
    $lw1team = $_POST['lw1team'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO team (lw_1_name, lw_1_number, lw_1_current_team) VALUES ('$lw1name', '$lw1number', '$lw1team')";

    mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
    wp_die(); 
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_rma_team_post', 'rma_team_post');
add_action('wp_ajax_rma_team_post', 'rma_team_post');
```

And the jQuery/AJAX:

```
(function($) {

    $(document).on( 'click', '#submitTeamButton', function( event ) {

          event.preventDefault();
          $.ajax( {
              url: team_ajax_object.ajax_url,
              method: "post",
              data: {
                action: 'rma_team_post',
            },
              dataType: "text",
              success: function(strMessage) {
                  $("#main").text('Team saved to blog');
              }
          });
      });

    })(jQuery);
```

When I click the "Post Team to Blog" button, I see my "success" message, but it doesn't actually write anything to my database (unless, as I mentioned, I hard code values into the variables). I've tried this a lot of different ways to no avail. Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Just FYI, I suggest you look into $wpdb. if you're using wordpress, might as well use what it offers too. They have a full database class you can use with prepared statements instead of this manual ini / database jazz you have going on here.

Comment: +1 @KaiQing. One of the main benefits of using WordPress is using it's robust [`$wpdb`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class. @Ruby A, you could remove almost half of your code making it easier to manage. For instance the 'lw' things could be summized into 3 lines. `global $wpdb;`, `$lwQuery = "SELECT lw.name, lw.number, lw.currentTeam, lw.position, lw.teamAbbr FROM lwing ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4";` and `$lw_results = $wpdb->get_results( $lwQuery);`. The `$wpdb` class handles all the DB connection nonsense for you.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks! I have actually tried that, as far as this code goes, and it didn't work. I wrote the backend code to scrape the NHL API for rosters prior to beginning to work with my WP site, so that info is in a separate database, but I agree I should refactor.